# Node server routes all timing out

Tags: node.js, git

No idea what happened... It was working and then it wasnt.

I am currently building a web app and decided to take some time off from the product side and build a landing page.

For some reason, I decided to build the landing page on a separate Github branch. So I checked out to a new branch, deleted everything, and started working on the landing page.

I soon realized this is a terrible idea and created a new repo to store my landing page.

I checked back into my master branch and spun my Node server up but for some reason now, everything is timing out. I opened Postman and tried hitting some of my endpoints but after like 3 minutes of loading, it tells me that it could not get any response and that there was an error connecting to `localhost:3001/api/posts`

In my terminal, all I see is this when I hit the route:

```
GET /api/posts - - ms - -
```

This has never happened to me before and I am completely clueless on WTH happened.

I tried deleting my local stuff and re-cloning the repo and installing my dependencies but to no avail...

Would love to know if someone has an idea on what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Check first is this isn't because of another process already listening on that port (but using resources which were deleted or not properly updated)

Closing applications or even rebooting can help you asserting if the issue is permanent or just linked to your current session.

The [OP Syn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4036130/syn) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56285321/node-server-routes-all-timing-out/56286054#comment99211254_56286054)  [the `~/.env` file missing](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/heres-how-you-can-actually-use-node-environment-variables-8fdf98f53a0a#d03d)

> `.env` files allow you to put your environment variables inside a file.
>   You just create a new file called `.env` in your project and slap your variables in there on different lines.
>
> To read these values, there are a couple of options, but the easiest is to use the `dotenv` package from `npm`.
>
> ```
> npm install dotenv --save
> ```

Note: it is generally *not* versioned, as it includes potentially sensitive date.

Comment: Hey VonC, I tried checking if someting was already using that port by changing what port my server was listening on. I also restarted my PC to see if something would change but no luck...